# Get first row in UITableView where unknown number of first sections are empty

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need the index path of the first row in a tableview under these conditions:

1. The first row could be off screen and so not in calls to methods that return an array of visible rows.
2. The first row's section is unknown, could be greater than 0, and the total number of sections is variable. This results from prior sections returning 0 to `[UITableViewDataSource numberOfRowsInSection:]` calls.

I could cycle through each section looking for rows but was wondering if UITableView has a better way to do this?

Comment: This is very unclear. What row exactly are you looking for? What `if` statement would match the row?

Comment: The first row in the tabieview. The tricky part is that the first row may or may not be in section 0. It could be in section 20 or 54 or any number within the number of sections in the tableview.

Comment: That still makes no sense. How can the first row in the table view be anything other than section 0, row 0? The only other possible definition of "first row" is the topmost visible row but it seems that isn't what you want either.

Comment: If you return 0 to number of rows in section then no rows appear in the tableview for that section. If this happens for section 0 then there is no row in the tableview for section 0 row 0. That is the essence of the problem. How do I find the first row if there is no row at 0,0 but there are rows in the table?

Comment: Aha. Now you've described the problem. You want the indexPath of the row for the first section in the table view that has 1 or more rows in it.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for looking into this problem. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems you want to know the index path of the row in the first section of the table view that has 1 or more rows.

Your only option is to iterate through your data source section by section until the section has 1 or more rows in it. Then the desired row will have an `indexPath` of row 0 and the section you just found.

There is no shortcut available through the table view to get this info.

Though there is one possible shortcut but it requires that your table view use "Plain" style (not "Grouped") and your table view can't have any header or footer views for any of the sections. If all of that is true, you can get the indexPath of the row you want by using the `UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:` and pass in `CGPointMake(5, 5)`. That will give the index path of the topmost row in the whole table view.